# Weird (incorrect) rounding in Python

Tags: python, rounding

This is my code:

```
foo = 1.345
print("%.2f" % foo)
foo = 1.346
print("%.2f" % foo)
```

I expected to get 1.35 in both cases, but the first one returns 1.34. Why?

Comment: Where do the docs say the formatting string should round?

Comment: But it does in some cases.
For example for 1.346 prints 1.35.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Maybe I should give other title to this question, but it dosen't simple cutting off unwanted numbers. In some cases it do round in others it doesn't. That's why I'm confussed.

*this is an answer for comment that was deleted